# How to get the range of selected lines in Visual lines mode?

Tags: neovim

I want to make a visual mode operator for commenting lines. I have achieved this in normal mode by getting lines with `nvim_win_get_cursor()` and `vim.v.count`, but how can I get starting and ending lines of range in visual mode? Or do I need to get that range to create an operator?

Comment: Maybe the commentary plugin from tpope helps you: https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary? You would simply do `gc` and the visual selection would be commented (it also works in normal mode with `gc{motion}` etc.). There's also https://github.com/tomtom/tcomment_vim (but I've not used that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the position of the beginning and end of the visual selection with marks `'<` and `'>`. But note that these marks are only available *after* you leave Visual mode, so in effect they refer to the beginning and end of the *last* Visual mode selection. But this is the typical situation you're in, since whenever you go to command-line mode or use `:call` to invoke a function, Vim will have left Visual mode already.

I believe you can use the `nvim_buf_get_mark()` NeoVim API to get the position of those marks. (In Vimscript, you would use `getpos("'<")` and `getpos("'>")`.)

Comment: Yes I find out the answer from this source too. It was using `getpos('v')`

https://github.com/b3nj5m1n/kommentary/blob/main/lua/kommentary/init.lua